What is the best way to turn a macro into a rule in bazel?
Let's say I have a bazel macro that generates a set of rules.  Suppose I want to rewrite my macro function as a rule.  What is the best way to create a bazel rule that is a composite of other, existing rules?  Is there a standard design pattern for this?
I know that I could replace, say, a py_library rule with something that creates and returns a (set of) PyInfo providers, but I'd rather not re-invent the py_library wheel if I can avoid it.
